# SSRS typical Matrix Report

Tags: reporting-services, matrix

I got a typical matrix report requirement from my client. I need your suggestions/ideas.

I have a table named Inventory (see the Image 'table')

I need the following format in the SSRS REPORT

(See the image 'SSRS REPORT'[image])
[image]

I tried to do it by using matrix report by grouping only the column with bucket, but it is showing me only one row. Not used grouping for partyname, region, bill_to_country.

Please advise!!

Comment: In a matrix with that data you will only get one row for the stoling/ap/ch combination with the 40/60/80 in their respective columns. You would need to group it on another column or something to get the result you have displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by using SQL SERVER PIVOT relational operator.

Instead of grouping in the SSRS report, i thought of implementing rotation logic(converting row values to column names) from SQL query and it worked like charm!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using party_name, region, bill_to_country *plus* bucket in row group